# Show hide grid view depending on session if its empty or not

Tags: asp.net

The problem is even the Session is empty it also dose not show up the grid

```
if (Session["User"] != null)
        {
            GridView1.Visible = false;


        }

        else
        {
            GridView1.Visible = true;
        }
```

Comment: Make sure that the GridView is not empty.

Comment: Does the gridview have a data source ? When is it bound ? Is the data source null or empty ? Have you tried stepping through the code and inspecting the values of variables in the watch window ?